# C++ Specific Date Time Values to Milliseconds and vice versa

Tags: c++, datetime

I have specific date and time values in milliseconds detail such as;

```
year = 2020
month = 8 (August)
day = 5
hour = 15
minute = 45
second = 58
milliseconds = 997
```

I do not want to get the current date and time in milliseconds.

I need to convert these values to a total milliseconds value and add a milliseconds value such as 40 milliseconds to total milliseconds value. Then I need to convert the resulting milliseconds value to date and time again.

How can I do that? I came up with the following code, but there is no millisecond resolution in tm;

```
tm specTime;
specTime.tm_year = dataLine.year - 1900;
specTime.tm_mon = dataLine.month - 1;
specTime.tm_mday = dataLine.day;
specTime.tm_hour = dataLine.hour;
specTime.tm_min = dataLine.min;
specTime.tm_sec = dataLine.sec;

time_t millis = mktime(&specTime);
```

Comment: XY Answer: [Take a look at the <chrono> library added in C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono). It can handle a wide variety of precisions

Comment: Why `dataLine.hour - 1`?  That isn't right.

Comment: Although some systems do add a microseconds value to `tm`, that isn't really necessary here.  `mktime` will return integer seconds.  If your `milliseconds+40` is less than 1000, then no adjustment is necessary.  Otherwise, add 1 to the seconds and convert it back.

Comment: C++20 adds a number of date and time capabilities to those of C++11. If you can't use C++20 for one reason or another, [here's a link to a library that provides, more or less, the same functionality](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Comment: But  I need the milliseconds value even the milliseconds+40 is less than 1000.

Comment: Yes, sorry not 'hour - 1'

Comment: When you say "total milliseconds value", do you mean with respect to a specific epoch?  Or could it be any epoch?  Does the shift between date and millisecond-count forms need to take a time zone into account?  If so, which one?  Conversely, if both forms of the date share the same time zone, then the time zone doesn't matter, as long as the starting point is a valid date-time in the time zone.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem with Tim's suggestion.